# AJAX and REST API calls

Tags: ajax, rest

I am trying to create an AJAX script that will pull data via an API and display it on a page as HTML.  Everything using the route below seem to work fine in Postman, but I can't get it to translate in my JS file.

I know I'm calling the URL incorrectly and I'm pretty sure it's because of the :id.  I'm not sure how to correct it.  I feel like I've tried every URL iteration, but I'm missing something.

```
// router.REST_VERB('EXPRESS_ROUTE', api.ACTION)
router.get('/', api.list);
router.post('/', api.create);
router.get('/:id', api.read);
router.put('/:id', api.update);
router.get('/delete/:id', api.delete);
```

Here are my update and delete:

```
/ AJAX PUT - Update Reminder
function updateReminder(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '/api/',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'id': $('#editId').val(),
      'name': $('#name').val(),
      'occasion': $('#occasion').val(),
      'lastgift': $('#lastgift').val()
    }), 
    success: (item) => { 
      document.location.href="/";
    },
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json'
    });
}

// AJAX DELETE request - Delete Reminder
function deleteReminder(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/api',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'id': id
    }), 
    success: (item) => { 
      document.location.href="/delete";
    },
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the controller code for update and delete:

```
ApiController.update = (req, res) => {
reminderService.update(
    req.params.id,
    {
        name: req.body.name,
        occasion: req.body.occasion,
        lastgift: req.body.lastgift,
        prefgift: req.body.prefgift
    },
    {new: true}
)
.then((item) => {
    res.json(item);
})
.catch((err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
};

ApiController.delete = (req, res) => {
reminderService.delete(req.params.id)
    .then((item) => {
        res.json(item);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.end("Didn't delete")
        }
    });
};
```

and here is the service code:

```
ReminderService.update = (id, reminderObj) => {
return Reminder.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
        {
            $set: reminderObj
        },
        {
            new: true
        }
    )

    .then((item) => {
        return item;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
                if (err) {  
                    res.end("You're in reminderService!")
                }                
    });
};

ReminderService.delete = (reminderId) => {
return  Reminder.deleteOne({ '_id': reminderId })
.then((item) => {
    return item;
})
.catch((err) => {
    throw err;
});
};
```

Comment: How does the postman request look like?

Comment: postman isn't pulling from the JS file, so update works fine.  I get a < error on delete though

Comment: Are you getting all your routes working if you use postman? Can you show your postman request or how `api.update`  reads the data

Comment: In postman, GET, POST, and PUT all work.  (list, update, create).  Delete does not.  I'll edit the post to show api.update

Answer (score 0):

Your route for delete is wrong, you should use `delete` instead of `get`.

```
router.get('/', api.list);
router.post('/', api.create);
router.get('/:id', api.read);
router.put('/:id', api.update);
router.delete('/:id', api.delete);
```

In your ajax requests, your url is missing the ids

```
// AJAX PUT - Update Reminder
function updateReminder(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '/'+id,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'id': $('#editId').val(),
      'name': $('#name').val(),
      'occasion': $('#occasion').val(),
      'lastgift': $('#lastgift').val()
    }), 
    success: (item) => { 
      document.location.href="/";
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}

// AJAX DELETE request - Delete Reminder
function deleteReminder(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/'+id,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'id': id
    }), 
    success: (item) => { 
      document.location.href="/delete";
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

One thing I'm skeptical about is that you use JSON.stringify on your data. Does your API specifically require JSON or did you do just do that to try to get it t work?

Comment: It's funny you say that.  I have 2 controllers.  One is an API and one is not.  I'm slightly worried my app.js is ignoring the api and going straight to the other file.  that said, my api.js does set the content type to json.